# Bluetooth beacon Scanning using android beacon library

Tags: java, android, android-ibeacon

I have a problem every time i open an activity (`blueToothSearch.java`) the following error occurs in my logcat.

```
    12-04 18:57:52.317 5354-5354/com.example.admin.paniccenter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.paniccenter, PID: 5354
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.paniccenter/com.example.admin.paniccenter.blueToothSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.<init>(BeaconManager.java:323)
    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(BeaconManager.java:315)
    at com.example.admin.paniccenter.blueToothSearch.<init>(blueToothSearch.java:65)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Below is my `blueToothSearch` activity which i want to use to display a list of beacons in my region.

```
    public class blueToothSearch extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
    private static final String TAG = "blueToothSearch";

    private ViewPagerAdapter viewadapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public  Toolbar toolbar;
    //public static Handler UIHandler;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1234;
    //public static final String EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY = "extrasTargetActivity";
    //private static final String JAALEE_BEACON_PROXIMITY_UUID = "EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524";//Jaalee BEACON Default UUID
   // private static final Region ALL_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);
    //public static final String EXTRAS_BEACON = "extrasBeacon";
    public BeaconManager beaconManager =  BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getBaseContext());
    private ArrayList<Beacon> arrayL = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
    private BeaconServiceUtility beaconUtill = null;

    private BeaconAdapter adapterr;
    public ListView list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        viewadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");
        //Set up the View Pager with the View page adapter
        myViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
        //tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_popup_sync_24);

        setupViewPager(myViewPager);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        myViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0: fab.show();

                        break;

                    case 1: fab.hide();

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        adapterr = new BeaconAdapter();
        list =  findViewById(R.id.beaconlist);
        list.setAdapter(adapterr);
        //list.setOnItemClickListener(createOnItemClickListener());
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new blueToothSearch.bluetooth(), "Available Devices");
        adapter.addFragment(new bluetoothProperties(), "Device Properties");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                connectToService();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void connectToService(){

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


/**
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener createOnItemClickListener(){
        return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                if (getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY) != null){
                    try {
                        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(blueToothSearch.this, clazz );
                        Beacon temp = adapterr.getItem(pos);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_BEACON, temp);

                        if(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY).contains("com.example.admin.paniccenter.CharacteristicsDemoActivity"))
                        {
                            startActivity(intent);
  //                          if (temp.getProximityUUID().equalsIgnoreCase(JAALEE_BEACON_PROXIMITY_UUID)) {
   //                             startActivity(intent);
  //                          }

   //           else
   //           {
    //          ListBeaconsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                //{
    //              public void run()
    //              {
                            //Toast.makeText(ListBeaconsActivity.this, "Current Beacon is in Non-Connectable mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                  }

        //          });
       //       }



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Finding class by name failed", e);
                    }


                }
            }
        };
    }

 */



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.scan_menu, menu);
        MenuItem refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
        refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return  true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

     beaconUtill.onStart(beaconManager, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        beaconUtill.onStop(beaconManager, this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Scanning...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning for devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                arrayL.clear();
                arrayL.addAll((ArrayList<Beacon>) beacons);
                adapterr.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didEnterRegion");
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didExitRegion");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didDetermineStateForRegion");
            }
        });

        connectToService();
    }


    public static class bluetooth extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "bluetooth";
        private int position;
        private TextView textv;
        private ViewPagerAdapter viewadapter;
        private ViewPager myViewPager;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private FragmentActivity myContext;



        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            //hideAction = (HideActionBar)getContext();
            myContext = (FragmentActivity)getContext();
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //position = getArguments().getInt("pos");


            //toolbar.getMenu().clear();


        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_search, container, false);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_search, container, false);

        //TextView text = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view);
        //text.setText("i am the real text ");




            //hideAction.customBlueToothToolbar();

            //FloatingActionButton fl = (FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
            //fl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_popup_sync_24);
            return view;


        }



        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }




    }

    public class BeaconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Beacon> beacons;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayL.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Beacon getItem(int arg0) {
            return arrayL.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            try {
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView != null) {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                } else {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
                }
                if (beacons.get(position).getParserIdentifier() != null)
                    holder.beacon_uuid.setText("UUID: " + arrayL.get(position).getParserIdentifier());

                holder.beacon_major.setText("Major: " + arrayL.get(position).getBeaconTypeCode());

                holder.beacon_minor.setText(", Minor: " + arrayL.get(position).getBluetoothName());

                holder.beacon_proximity.setText("Proximity: " + arrayL.get(position).getDistance());

                holder.beacon_rssi.setText(", Rssi: " + arrayL.get(position).getRssi());

                holder.beacon_txpower.setText(", TxPower: " + arrayL.get(position).getTxPower());

                holder.beacon_range.setText("" + arrayL.get(position).getExtraDataFields());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView beacon_uuid;
            private TextView beacon_major;
            private TextView beacon_minor;
            private TextView beacon_proximity;
            private TextView beacon_rssi;
            private TextView beacon_txpower;
            private TextView beacon_range;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                beacon_uuid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_uuid);
                beacon_major = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_major);
                beacon_minor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_minor);
                beacon_proximity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_proximity);
                beacon_rssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_rssi);
                beacon_txpower = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_txpower);
                beacon_range = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BEACON_range);

                view.setTag(this);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using a `BeaconManager` class to range and scan my beacons, the library is from package `org.altbeacon.beacon`

Comment: I have been puzzling with this for two days, any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe `BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication()` needs to be inside or after onCreate(). Looks like `Context` is `null` in `BeaconManager`, which might happen because the `Activity` isn't fully constructed yet.

Comment: Markus your wild guess is correct, Thank You times a 1000, it would be the most obvious thing to check but i guess it was sillyness on my part, Thanks again

Comment: Nice to hear. And it's of course common in Android that one needs to pay attention to the life cycle methods of Activities and Fragments to find a safe place to code referencing them, the context or any objects they own. You can add an answer yourself, if you like.